# How to iterate through a pandas dataframe with a timestamp index?

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through a dataframe using iterrows and pull out two columns values.  The index is a date/timestamp.

If the two columns are `signal` and `value`, I try:

```
for row in df_train.iterrows():
    for value in row:
        print(value['signal'])
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-148-34d711ac79ad>", line 3, in <module>
    print(value['RSI_20'])

TypeError: 'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iterrows` method actually yields two values: the index and the values of the row. So you should do:

```py
for ts, row in df_train.iterrows():
    print(ts, row['signal'], row['value'])
```